# Flutter - Resize network image

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

Is there a way to resize an image without having it previously written to storage?
I am using a pdf library that for the images needs the bytes of it.

What I do is get image with an http.get and I get the bytes to put it in the pdf.
The problem is that I need to resize the image BEFORE putting it in the pdf.

The only thing I have is the url of the image or the uint8list

```
Response response = await http.get(imageUrl);
Uint8List imgBytes = response.bodyBytes;
```

Later:

```
Image(
    PdfImage.file(pdf.document,
    bytes: imageBytes)
),
```

Pdf lib I use: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ui.instantiateImageCodec` and specify `targetHeight` and `targetWidth` 
You can see output image size become smaller after resize

code snippet

```
    String imageUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9';
    http.Response response = await http.get(imageUrl);
    originalUnit8List = response.bodyBytes;

    ui.Image originalUiImage = await decodeImageFromList(originalUnit8List);
    ByteData originalByteData = await originalUiImage.toByteData();
    print('original image ByteData size is ${originalByteData.lengthInBytes}');

    var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(originalUnit8List,
        targetHeight: 50, targetWidth: 50);
    var frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
    ui.Image targetUiImage = frameInfo.image;

    ByteData targetByteData =
        await targetUiImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    print('target image ByteData size is ${targetByteData.lengthInBytes}');
    targetlUinit8List = targetByteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

output of working demo

```
I/flutter (17023): original image ByteData size is 250000
I/flutter (17023): target image ByteData size is 4060
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Uint8List targetlUinit8List;
  Uint8List originalUnit8List;

  void _resizeImage() async {
    String imageUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9';
    http.Response response = await http.get(imageUrl);
    originalUnit8List = response.bodyBytes;

    ui.Image originalUiImage = await decodeImageFromList(originalUnit8List);
    ByteData originalByteData = await originalUiImage.toByteData();
    print('original image ByteData size is ${originalByteData.lengthInBytes}');

    var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(originalUnit8List,
        targetHeight: 50, targetWidth: 50);
    var frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
    ui.Image targetUiImage = frameInfo.image;

    ByteData targetByteData =
        await targetUiImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    print('target image ByteData size is ${targetByteData.lengthInBytes}');
    targetlUinit8List = targetByteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            originalUnit8List == null
                ? Container()
                : Image.memory(originalUnit8List),
            targetlUinit8List == null
                ? Container()
                : Image.memory(targetlUinit8List),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _resizeImage,
        tooltip: 'Resize',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```